# Wait for VCS labeling to finish before starting the next build in TeamCity chain

Tags: git, teamcity

Let's say I have two builds in my TeamCity build chain, both using the same VCS root. The **2nd** build starts after the **1st** one finishes (*the **2nd** has a snapshot dependency on the **1st***).

The **1st** build uses [VSC labeling](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/vcs-labeling.html) build feature and adds a new tag to Git repository after the build is done.

The problem I encounter is that the **2nd** build doesn't get this new tag. For instance, if I run `git describe` as the very first step of the **2nd** build, it will return the "previous" tag value. I believe, the reason for such "lag" is the fact that according to the TeamCity documentation:

> The [labeling] process takes place in the background after the build finishes

So when the **2nd** build does VCS checkout, the Git repository doesn't have the new tag yet (*as it is being applied in the background, apparently after the **2nd** build starts*), so for the **2nd** build the "previous" tag is actually the latest one available.

Is there a way to run the **2nd** build only *after* the VCS labeling is done?

I can think of adding a dummy step with some timeout to ensure that labeling process has enough time to finish, and only then run the **2nd** build, but that looks like an ugly crutch.

Comment: What are your polling times like for this repo? You can view in *administration > diagnostics > VCS status*

Comment: The **2nd** build triggers on **1st** successful build (*and snapshot dependency enforces revisions synchronization*), so polling doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: It may not matter, but it could give an indication of why the labeling is taking too long.

Comment: It's unlikely to be long, but the since the **2nd** build and VCS labeling start simultaneously (*or maybe the build goes even earlier than VCS labeling*), then it will be too late anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it appears to me that this is by design, so there is unlikely to be a solution for that. It is really a shame though, because using this default feature could have saved some effort.

So I decided to go with the following workaround: instead of using the VSC labeling build feature, I add a new tag in one of the build steps "manually", to ensure that this operation completes before the build is done.

Here's the workflow for better clarity:

1. The **1st** build starts
2. One of its build steps explicitly adds a new tag using CLI and Git. The new tag is now in my Git repository
3. The **1st** build finishes, and that triggers the **2nd** build start
4. The **2nd** build starts and gets the new tag with no problems

Since it's a workaround, I won't mark this answer as accepted.